# Move the contacts to a specific group in People hub of Outlook.com?

Tags: contacts, outlook.com

The drop down arrow next to 'ALL' on the people page of my Outlook has gone missing! This means that I can create contacts but I can't move them into a specific group anymore

Is there a way I can move the contacts to a specific group?

Answer (score 2):

To add a contact to a group:

1. Open the "People" tool.
2. Find the group in the list of people/groups on the left side. Select it.
3. Click "Edit" in the top menu
4. Start typing a name in the "Add Member" field. When the contact you want is displayed, click it. Repeat for however many contacts you want.
5. Click "Save" to save your contact group.

Why they've made so that you can only add people from the group, but not add a group to a person record, is beyond me. Of course, it might work better with Internet Explorer.